# How to make images/files downloadable

Tags: reactjs, dropzone.js, admin-on-rest, react-dropzone

I want to be able to download images/files. 
The way I am thinking this is like the remove button when hovering over the image. The ideal would be a download icon when image has rendered from server. My thought is something like this

```
<a href={srcValue} download>
```

and wrap img tag. And respectively for files.
So is there any more decent way to do this instead of overwriting all files (FileInput, FileInputPreview, ImageInput, ImageField etc)

Thanks!

Comment: can you edit your question? ``` able to download images/files when they are uploaded to the server``` this part is confusing

Comment: @ReiDien just deleted this. I meant when we use the field component from aor.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
export const Something = (props) => {
  return (
    <List {...props} >
      <Datagrid>
        <ReferenceField label="Get Image" source="id" reference="pathToImage" linkType={false} >
          <ImageLink />
        </ReferenceField>
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  )
}

const ImageLink = ({record}) => {
  return (
    <a href={config.staticHost + '/' + record.nameOnDisk} target="_blank" download >
      <FlatButton label="Download" />
    </a>
  )
}
```

You can skip the ReferenceField if your record contains the URL of the image. The you can just pass it the url from the record and not the entire record.